# Javascript: Page keeps crashing when attempting to load the file?

Tags: javascript, string, function

EDIT: [CSS](http://pastebin.com/He55Lces)
[Javascript](http://pastebin.com/dmbTNTfF)

My code is by no means demanding so I'm not sure why this is happening.
It doesn't seem to work on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahdg4mo/4/) either. Every time I try to load it on the website I get a 404 error.

This only happened after I made a small change in my code:

```
    function runDisplay(data, id) {
        var reader = document.getElementById(id);
        var index = 0;
        if (timer) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        if (data.length) {
            timer = setInterval(function() {
            reader.innerHTML = data[index++];
            var punctuation = [".", ",", ":", ";", "!", "?"];
            var word = data[index++];
            for (var j = 0; j < punctuation.length; j++) {
                if (!(word.indexOf(punctuation[j]) === -1)) {
                    word = string.replace(punctuation[j], '');
                }
            index = index % data.length;
          }, getTextSpeed()); // change speed dynamically in real time
        }
    }
    function getTextSpeed() {
        var speeds = document.getElementById("speed");
        return speeds.options[speed.selectedIndex].value;
    }
```

I changed a `textSpeed` variable to a direct call to the method `getTextSpeed` in an attempt to get the speed of the text to change dynamically.

Essentially what this class is supposed to display text word-by-word, with font-size and the speed (which must be implemented with `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`) by which the words are displayed being changeable by the user of the webpage.

If a word contains punctuation, then it is removed and the delay between that word and the next is doubled (234 ms instead of 117 ms). If there is more than one character of punctuation (ex: ...) then only one character of punctuation is removed.

Can you help me figure out what's causing this? Is it an error in my implementation? Did I accidentally create an infinite loop somewhere?

Comment: Not sure if its a copy paste error but you are missing a closing bracket in that code above. Also what does this `getTextSpeed` function look like/do?

Comment: if the change was to that function would make sense to show what that function does

Comment: Sorry. I just added `getTextSpeed` to the post.

Comment: If you need to see any other code, I posted a JSFiddle link.

Comment: Are talking about the two 404 errors in the console for the js and css file? I can't get it to do anything else in the jsfiddle. Maybe I am missing something. Maybe try to explain the process of repeating the error in the fiddle.

Comment: The main problem I'm having is being unable to actually load a page in a browser. When I attempt to open my speedreader.html file in Chrome or Firefox, it loads for a while and just crashes.

Comment: You need to use consistent indentation. In both your fiddle and your question its all over the place. As AtheistP3eace already noted it hides an error in your question.

Comment: The 404 errors in JSFiddle may or may not be related to that.

Comment: Are the js and css file its trying to load in fiddle required to reproduce the issue? You should add them as external files if so. Fiddle is trying to load them like they are local files sitting in the same directory. Everything outside of body tag is not needed in fiddle.

Comment: I'll try and do that.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see where I can upload the files aside from the external resources option which seems to require for me to upload the files somewhere  on the internet where they can be accessed through a link, then uploaded somewhere else?

Comment: Would it be easier for me to just make a pastebin or something?

Comment: Yes you can't upload the file. You need to host it elsewhere but if those files are required to reproduce the error you need to figure something out. Hard to help when we can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please check the post again. I added some links to the CSS and js code.

Comment: Sorry, but do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: The code you linked to is the js and css already in the fiddle. OK, lets start over. Please describe precisely how to reproduce the issue in the fiddle. I it something that happens onload or something that happens when using the page. If its something that happens using the page describe what you do to make it happen. If something needs to be entered into the text area to make it happen tell us a usable value. Make a step by step list on how to make the error happen.